# controller not recognized - angularJS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, coffeescript

I have a angular controller I have

```
@MyAngular = ($scope) -> 
    $scope.my = [...]
@MyAngular.$inject = ["$scope"]
```

I get this message error : `Argument 'MyAngular' is not a function, got undefined`. In my view, I have `%div{"ng-controller" => "MyAngular"}`

I found some SO posts and but nothing did the trick

Comment: what is this syntax `%div{"ng-controller" => "MyAngular"}`?

Comment: @sza it is `haml` syntax, but this is not the problem ;)

Comment: AngularJS is javascript. It has nothing to do with rails. Can you just  use `<div ng-controller="MyAngular">`

Comment: @sza %div{"ng-controller" => "MyAngular"} in an html.haml file is the exact equivalent of  <div ng-controller="MyAngular"> !

Comment: Ok. I am curious you are using too many frameworks for just simple javascript and html...haml, coffeescript... just for the sake of using that?

Comment: @sza no ;) I am working on `GitLab` and it uses plenty of frameworks !

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got i, I put in a more cleaner way

```
app = angular.module "MyApp", []
app.controller 'MyAngular', ['$scope', ($scope) ->
  $scope.my = [...]
]
```